# setting up one membership for a few asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

In sharing hosting provider I have a website and a few sub-domain which each one is a separate asp.net web-app with separate Database (SQL Server 2005) .

At the moment I use default ASP.NET Membership Provider for Users and Roles . I would like When a user register in one web-site , she could log-in to other websites too .( I mean doesn't force users to register in all websites ) 
How could i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the same data connection and `applicationName` defined for the [membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whae3t94.aspx) and [role manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164662.aspx) providers in each application.

The data connection attribute defined what database (obviously), and the application attribute then partitions the data within the database: if these are the same then the web apps are using the same information.